# django images from a from are not showing in templates

Tags: django-templates

I am sorry in advance if I am asking a stupid question but I have been trying to figure out what wrong is with my code for several hours and did not find an error. I am a beginner. When I submit the form, the form saves all the fields, including the image, to the admin site but the image does not appear on the template.

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
entry = models.TextField(max_length=100)
your_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

blog_objects = models.Manager()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.date} -- {self.name}"
```

---

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = BlogEntry
    fields = ['name', 'entry', 'your_img']
    
    labels = {

        "name": "Your name:",
        "entry": "Your adventure:",
        "your_img": "Upload image:",
    }

    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'entry': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "rows": "3"}),
    }
```

---

```
def blog_index(request): 
form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if request.method == "POST":
   if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
else: 
    form = BlogForm()

all_entries = BlogEntry.blog_objects.all().values().order_by('-id')
return render(request, 'blog.html', {'form': form, 'all_entries': all_entries})
```

---

```
            <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <button type="submit" style="width: 5em; "
                class="bg-info mt-4 p-2 d-inline-block text-center">Post</button>

        </form>
```

---

```
   {%for entry in all_entries %}
        <div class="" style="text-align: justify;"><img src="{{entry.your_img.url}}"
   {% endfor %}
```

---

```
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ) 
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```